How to upgrade OpenSSH on Debian 12?
On Debian 12 (the latest available Debian distrib at OVH), I'd like to upgrade OpenSSH.
# ssh -V

OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u2, OpenSSL 3.0.11 19 Sep 2023

So the installed version is 9.2. For PCI compliance, I need 9.6 or more, overwise the securitymetrics fails. I can see here that 9.7 is available.
I've tried to apt upgrade but it doesn't work, as 9.2 is already the newest (available) version.
# apt-get update
# apt-get upgrade ssh

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
ssh is already the newest version (1:9.2p1-2+deb12u2).
Calculating upgrade... Done

The only solution i've founded is here but it is very complicated. People say it is dangerous and not recommanded.
Is there a secure way to upgrade ?
Note that SecurityMetrics has not tested for these issues but has instead relied only on the application's self-reported version number. So I can not get the PCI compliance until I can get the good version number, even if the issues are fixed :-(
PS: I guest this is easy for a Linux expert, but I'm not good enought...
Edit : As recommanded by Stephen and Marcus, I sent and email to securitymetrics to submit a false positive.

You shouldn’t need to upgrade your OpenSSH package, the Debian package includes fixes for all known, important vulnerabilities in OpenSSH 9.2. See the package changelog and security tracker for details.
This is true of all major release-based distributions (Debian, RHEL etc.): security issues in most programs are fixed by backporting the relevant fix, not upgrading to the latest version of the program. As recommended in the post you found, the best approach here is to explain the situation to your PCI auditor, not manually upgrade OpenSSH. Doing the latter will end up putting you in a worse situation security-wise, since you will no longer get security updates to OpenSSH from your distribution.

The securitymetrics test fails. Thx to your answer, I would think it is only based on the version number. Despite the security issues are fixed, my website can not get the PCI 4 compliance. Securitymetrics asks to upgrade to OpenSSH version 9.6 or later.

Tests are just an indicator. Unfortunately, many PCI validation tools don’t take distribution practices into account. Presumably you’ve already chosen SecurityMetrics so you might be a bit stuck; but manually upgrading to OpenSSH 9.7 would actually reduce your overall security, because you wouldn’t get automatic security fixes in the future.

Yes @Stephen Kitt  , SecurityMetrics has not tested for these issues but has instead relied only on the application's self-reported version number. My website uses Braintree by PayPal, and they impose SecurityMetrics

@thierryler talk to them. Making your security worse to make a dumb tool happy is the opposite of what you'd get a PCI cert for. Like, it's literally saying "yes, I understand the security problem, but I still do what seems easy". So, talk to whoever you need to talk to. Getting checked for compliance shouldn't make you less secure, just because their tooling is bad. No excuses.

SecurityMetrics do provide support for false-positives with a 48h SLA, so you could try contacting them. You won’t be their first customer in this situation — I know there are certified PCI DSS 4 sites using distribution-provided OpenSSH on Debian and RHEL (which uses older base OpenSSH packages).

Thx Stephen and Marcus. I just sent an email, as you recommanded. I hope they will answer.

After multiple emails to Security Metrics, the issu is still open :-( And they ask more and more...

Now that RegreSSHion is in the wild, I really need to know how to do this process myself. Can someone actually answer the question instead of dodging it like this answer does?

@Kamilion that’s CVEs 2024-6387 and 2024-6409; security fixes have been released in all affected Debian releases. If your Debian systems are up-to-date you’re fine.
